# PHP multi upload files with custom title

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem with my MySQL insert. When I upload a file, data like "filename", "time", and "gid" are inserted correctly. But "title" is empty.

Why is the "title" not being inserted?

```php
<?php

$max_no_img = 10; // Maximum number of images value to be set here
echo "<form method=post action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<table border='0' width='400' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' align=center>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_no_img; $i++) {
    echo " <tr><td><input type='text' name='title[]'></td><td><input type=file name='images[]' class='bginput'></td></tr>";
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='gid' value='$info[id]'>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br /> <center><input type=submit value='Dodaj sliku'></center>";
echo "</form>";

while (list($key, $value) = each($_FILES['images']['name'])) {

    // echo $key;
    // echo "<br />";
    // echo $value;
    // echo "<br />";

    if (!empty($value)) { // this will check if any blank field is entered
        $time = time();
        $gid = addslashes($_POST['gid']);
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $filename = rand(1, 100000) . $value; // filename stores the value
        $filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename); // Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line
        $add = "slike/$filename"; // upload directory path is set

        // echo $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];     // uncomment this line if you want to display the file type
        // echo "<br />";                             // Display a line break

        copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO slike (title,slika,time,gid) VALUES ('$title','$filename','$time','$gid')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Uspesno pritisnite <a href='/admin/?page=gall&id=$info[id]'>ovde</a>";

        //  upload the file to the server

        chmod("$add", 0777); // set permission to the file.
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming that uploads always succeed. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILEs for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just as your script handles multiple uploaded images, each image has a corresponding title input.

```html
<input type='text' name='title[]'>
```

So, the "title" data will be posted as an array:

```
Array (
  [0] => title1
  [1] => title2
  [2] => title3
  [3] => title4
)
```

You'll need to handle the array of titles appropriately, by using a key that corresponds to the array of uploaded images to reference each associated title. From the looks of your code, you may be able to use the `$key` variable that is defined in your `while` loop, like so:

```php
$title = $_POST['title'][$key];
```

Note: There also seem to be a couple of extra closing braces `}` in your PHP code.